# Firefox fullscreen excludes top line of pixels?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, onmousemove

Im writing an HTML5 RTS game. As typical in RTS games, players can scoll when moving the mouse cursor to the edge of the screen. In FF fullscreen theres a problem, the very top line of pixels seems to be not inside of the browser window anymore. onmousemove() does not fire when moving the mouse inside of the top line of pixels in FF fullscreen. Other browsers work fine. This way scrolling upwards doesnt work, since when the cursor is at the very top, the event doesnt fire anymore and i lose track of the cursor position. Does anybody have a solution for this ?

Comment: Make the top two lines of pixels scrollable?

Comment: the top ~20 are scrollable. The thing is when you move the corsor up there fast the even maybe fires as 25 px and the next time it would fire its already at 1px (where it doesnt fire anymore), so my tracking stops at 25px ?

Comment: Try starting FF in Safe Mode and see if it's still an issue.

Comment: btw this is not only me but other ppl, too